# Keras/ImageGenerator/ Split data to train and validation/CNN

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras

I have question about the Keras CNN
Is it ok to train and validation with same data?

If i have to separate them,

How do i separate those where in one forder (There are 5 classes)

I am using ImageGenerator and model.fit_generator to train.. there are instruction to split data for model.fit but not for model.fit_generator.. thx

Answer (score 0):

If your test and train data sets are the same, then you have no way of determining whether or not you are overfitting.  This is because your test and train accuracy will be the same.  If you do not use a hold-out dataset for validation, you can have little confidence in the generalizability of your trained model.

Your file hierarchy can indicate which images are to be used for training and which images are to be used for validation.  The [keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) illustrates how this is done.  Look at the flow_from_directory() function being used to define the train and validation generators.

For example, if my file hierarchy were as follows:

```
data
├── train
│   ├── class1
│   ├── class2
│   ├── class3
│   ├── class4
│   └── class5
└── validation
    ├── class1
    ├── class2
    ├── class3
    ├── class4
    └── class5
```

then I could define the following generator for training on 64x64 images belong to 5 classes.

```
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(
        'data/train/',
        classes=['class1','class2','class3','class4','class5'],
        target_size=(64, 64),
        class_mode='categorical')
```

Comment: Hello, My data has 5 classes and each classes have 1000 images. I want 700 for train and other 300 for Validation. There are way to do it in model.fit, but not for generator... how do i do that ? thanks

Comment: Assuming you have a list of each of the 1000 images, you can randomly select indices from the lists as follows `indices = np.arange(1000); train_indices = np.random.choice(indices,700); test_indices = indices[~np.in1d(indices,train_indices)]; print(np.intersect1d(test_indices,train_indices))` and then use the indices to partion your images into train and validation sets.